# how to generate a cookie in text file

Tags: cookies, httpcookie

I'm wondering if it's possible to generate a cookie and save it in a text file. The requirement is to generate a cookie for any domain not only that you own.  After all the cookies are plain text but the "space" and path ("/") seems to make it a bit tricky to reproduce using  manual programming (e.g not setcookie function ). Netscape seems to help but not I can't find a proof of concept shell/application to actually generate the cookie (not to get/receive/read it as curl does)  http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
 Basically I'm looking for a code snippet to see how this black magic works because I don't understand the spaces between the parameters . So far I identified the parameters required to generate a "valid" cookie .

```
Name
Content
Host
Path
Secure(true or false)
HTTP only(true or false)
Expires(optional)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible, all the major browser software does it.

**Update:**
cUrl apparently uses the Mozilla/Firefox cookie format for permanent (not session) cookies. Here is a [good blog article](http://xiix.wordpress.com/2006/03/23/mozillafirefox-cookie-format/) describing that format. Writing it should be simply a matter of writing a text file in this format.

Comment: actually I'm looking for a code snippet to see how that is done . I'm trying for 2 days to generate(manually) a cookie with php and still couldn't make it So far I have found only the parameters required to generate it (question updated)

Comment: What are you using this for. Is it just a cookie for your app to store session information for a user? If your app is the consumer the file can be in any format you like. If you need cookies in the format of a specific 3rd party application you will have to specify which one.

Comment: I'm working on a security tool based on php cURL . basically I want to generate a cookie for a domain that I want , save it as a file , load it in cURL and then make the http request with the generated cookie. I know how to load the cookie in cURL but I don't know how to generate it manually before load .

Answer (score 1):

Simple code can be this:

```
$domain = '.go.com';
$expire = time() + 3600;
$name   = 'fruit';
$value  = 'apple';
file_put_contents($cookieJar, "\n$domain\tTRUE\t/\tFALSE\t$expire\t$name\t$value", FILE_APPEND);
```

But for advanced, This library allows you to manipulate (add, delete, update,...) Netscape Cookie File (eg. Cookies generated by CURL) :

https://github.com/kegi/netscape-cookie-file-handler